# Palindrome of int using lambda expression

Tags: java-8, functional-programming, palindrome

Is there a better way to find an integer is palindrome or not using lambda expression. I tried something like this, it worked but looking for better approaches.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {

    return number == IntStream.iterate(number, i -> i / 10)
        .map(n -> n % 10)
        .limit(String.valueOf(number).length())
        .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a = a * 10 + b);
}
```

Comment: better in terms of performance? readability?

Comment: Also, your current approach is incorrect in some cases as the input `1001` yields `false` when in fact it should be `true`.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to remove the redundant filter before posting

Comment: It will give you the intended result now

Comment: can explain what you mean by _better_ ? do you in terms of performance? readability? or both (if possible)?

Comment: I didn't liked the way I have imposed the limit, is there any better way to break out of the iteration

Comment: e.g. by checking the value of i in the iterate method

Comment: This question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: BTW is 010 a palindrome? or is -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to find if an integer is a palindrome or not but since this question is only limited to using lambda expressions, I will therefore only suggest improvements to your current solution.

Unfortunately, with JDK-8 you'll need to use `limit` to truncate the infinite stream. However, as of JDK-9, there is an [iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method with the signature:

```
static <T> Stream<T> iterate(T seed,
                             Predicate<? super T> hasNext,
                             UnaryOperator<T> next)
```

So, instead of doing `.limit(String.valueOf(number).length())` you can now do:

```
return number == IntStream.iterate(number, n -> n != 0, i -> i / 10)
                          .map(n -> n % 10)
                          .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a * 10 + b);
```

Note that doing `a = a * 10 + b` in the `reduce` is redundant hence I've changed it to `a * 10 + b` as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to a string and check for the equality of the reverse string.

```
return number -> Integer.toString(number)
                          .equals(new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(number))
                            .reverse().toString());
```

Or

```
return number -> String.valueOf(number).equals(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(number)).reverse().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10 digit number , you need to compare half of the way to know whether given number is palindrome or not. we are converting number to string then dividing the length by 2 , then comparing left side char with right side char (means 0th char should match with last char, same way for other index's, left to right char comparison ) as soon as any comparison fails we can return false instead of checking all other chars that's how we can reduce half of the time.

```
int num = 121;
        String temp = Integer.toString(num);
        boolean val = IntStream.range(0,temp.length()/2).noneMatch(i -> temp.charAt(i) != temp.charAt(temp.length()-i-1));
        System.out.println("result "+val);
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail to clarify how this answer is better than the one provided?

Comment: if you have 10 digit number , you need to compare half of the way to know whether given number is palindrome or not . we are converting number to string then dividing the length by 2 , then comparing left side char with right side char (means 0th char should match with last char, same way for other index's, left to right char comparison ) as soon as any comparison fails we can return false instead of checking all other chars that's how we can reduce half of the time.

Comment: @RameshGidda: That’s a useful explanation. Please [edit] your answer to include it.